# how to set 3D mode in our Xamarin forms by using UrhoSharp package or if possible by some other package

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a project and in that project there are some 3d model which we have to set and perform 360 degree product viewer in that model.
this is the reference link .we want our product like this 
https://www.webrotate360.com/products/webrotate-360-product-viewer.aspx

I tried many thing but not get any good idea about this

Answer (score 0):

you could look at this and maybe help you https://github.com/xamarin/urho-samples ,The 'FormsSamples' solution demonstrates how UrhoSharp can be used in Xamarin.Forms applications as a View element.

Comment: urho sample are lil bit confusing and is being complicated when we are implementing it ..